# os.path.isdir not returning True when given paths to actual existing directories

Tags: python, os.path

I have the following code:

```
path = os.path.join(svn_drive, svn_repo_path, relative_path)
if os.path.isdir(path.encode('string-escape')):             
            print path, " is  a directory"
else:               
            print path, " is not a directory"
```

this results in the following:

```
D:\mysvn\trunk\Assets\myfile.max  is not a directory    
D:\mysvn\\Animations  is not a directory
....
```

i.e. the problem is that `os.path.isdir` doesn't seems to recognize the fact that the `path` is actually a directory

`svn_drive` is the drive letter in this case `D:`
`svn_repo_path` is in this case `mysvn`
`relative path` is a path relative to the svn repo (that I obtained by parsing the results of svn log)

I have tried escaping, not escaping, many `os.path` methods (`abspath`, `basename`, etc) and nothing seems to work :(

I also accept alternatives ;), I just want to be able to know a path and then email the files, don't really mind how (I know sometimes people want to keep their code, but this is just a stand alone script)

I also need to open the file at a later stage to email it and I get a file not found that I am going to guess starts here

Full function listing (in case it helps):

```
def parse_svn_results(lines, svn_drive, svn_repo_path): 
    result = []
    for x in lines.split("\n"):
        if  "trunk/" in x:
            relative_path = x.lstrip('MDA ').replace("/","",1).replace("/", os.sep)
            path = os.path.join(svn_drive, svn_repo_path, relative_path)
            if os.path.isdir(path.encode('string-escape')):             
                print path, " is  a directory"
            else:               
                print path, " is not a directory"
                result.append(path)
    return result
```

**UPDATE**

this is a workaround version of the code but still I can't do `imghdr.what(filename)` (where `filename` is one of the files in result)

```
def parse_svn_results(lines, svn_drive, svn_repo_path):
    result = []
    for x in lines.split("\n"):
        if "trunk/" in x:
            relative_path = x.lstrip('MDA ').replace("/", "", 1).replace("/", os.sep)
            temp_path = os.path.join(svn_drive, os.sep, svn_repo_path, relative_path)
            path = format_path(temp_path)
            if path is not None:
                result.append(path)
    return result


def format_path(file_destination):
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_destination)
    path = os.path.dirname(file_destination)
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)
    picture_format = None
    e = ext if picture_format is None else '.%s' % picture_format.lower()
    if e:
        to_path = os.path.join(path, base + e)
        return to_path
```

Comment: What exactly are `svn_drive`, `svn_repo_path` and `relative_path`. How are they generated? Why are you using `.encode()`?

Comment: updated the question with that info

Comment: I am using encode because I was trying the same thing in the REPL and it worked (ie isdir returned true)

Comment: please quote the value of any `temp_path` and `path` pair

Answer (score 1):

I think `svn_drive` should be `D:/` not `D:`. See this line in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

> Note that on Windows, since there is a current directory for each drive, os.path.join("c:", "foo") represents a path relative to the current directory on drive C: (c:foo), not c:\foo.

Comment: I just tried that and didn't make a difference . I also just tried running that in the REPL and os.path.join('D:', os.sep, 'whatever') was the only thing that returned a valid path:  


>>> os.path.join('D:', 'mypath')
'D:mypath'
>>> os.path.join('D:\', 'mypath')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    os.path.join('D:\', 'mypath')
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> os.path.join('D:\\, 'mypath')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    os.path.join('D:\\, 'mypath')
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> os.path.join('D:',os.sep, 'mypath')
'D:\\mypath'

Comment: Sorry I don't have a VM on this machine, does os.path.join('D:/', 'whatever') work?

Comment: no worries, I tried on REPL and it returns 'D:/mypath' then I tried on the script above and the same (dirs are not recognised) :       d:/mysvn\trunk\TexturePacker  is not a directory

Comment: A weird thing, if i do the folowing on the REPL os.path.isdir("d:/mysvn\texturepacker".encode('string-escape'))  this returns true (the directory exists of course) however running the same line from withing the python script returns false

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a point in using the `encode` but if it's an absolute must then I suggest you further condition it's result by passing it through `os.path.normpath` and then throw it onto `os.path.isdir`

Comment: I have no problem removing encode, when I do, I get the same behaviour. A bit unrelated but even trying imghdr.what(os.path.normpath(filename)) or imghdr.what(filename) or encoded they all give me an IO error (I ve verified that the files are there)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution came from another question, I had to strip the \r at the end , I was sure that was being added by path.join but nope
[python filename on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445885/python-filename-on-windows)

Comment: in similar situations `print`ing the variable being passed is usually quite a helpful practice while debugging. And please elaborate the answer a bit more and mark it as answered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer BTW I did use print but I stupidly(?) thought that os.path.normpath would either fail or deal with the fact it didnt look like a path and fix it.

Comment: `help` is really convenient quick lookup. Simply `help(os.path.normpath)`. plus you could do `op = os.path` to save some typing. And please click on the help link in the bottom right side of the comment box for some quick formatting tidbits. They make reading posts easier, akin to indentations which make reading and writing code easier.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, really appreciate it :D