# python filename on windows

Tags: python, windows

Disclaimer I have a similar thread started but I think it got too big and convoluted

In short this is the problem

```
import imghdr
import os.path
....
image_type = imghdr.what(os.path.normpath(filename))
```

fails with

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'D:\\mysvn\\trunk\\Assets\\models\\character\\char1.jpg\r'
```

Where the aforementioned file does exist

Help? :D

Comment: Thanks :D how can I remove that programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a carriage return character `\r` at the end of the filename. That is not a valid character for a Windows filename, so I doubt the filename will work.

Use `.rstrip('\r')` to remove it:

```
image_type = imghdr.what(os.path.normpath(filename.rstrip('\r')))
```

`.rstrip()` removes characters from the end of a string, and only those in the set that you name.

Since this is a filename, *any* whitespace around the filename is probably incorrect, so a straight-up `.strip()` would work too:

```
image_type = imghdr.what(os.path.normpath(filename.strip()))
```

This would remove tabs, newlines, carriage returns and spaces from both the start *and* end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'D:\\...\\char1.jpg\r'
                                                    ^^
```

You have a trailing carriage return in the file path. Strip it first:

```
filename = filename.strip()
```